# How to remove property from document embedded in array using MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Using native Nodejs driver with MongoDB 2.4 and trying to remove property from documents embedded in array. E.g. how can I remove `gym` property from documents embedded in `grades` array where `gym` is `562e7c1ae6c3e8ce29abfe05`? So from this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("562abaaffb5870b8fb9dca3f"),
    "grades" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("562e7bbe70ee82bb290192bd"),
            "discipline" : "55aae5b7848b9c8bf4ecbb5c",
            "grade" : "55aae5b7848b9c8bf4ecbb4c",
            "gym" : "562e7c1ae6c3e8ce29abfe06",
            "registeredOn" : ISODate("2015-10-26T19:15:10.565Z")
        },
        {
            "discipline" : "55aae5b7848b9c8bf4ecbb5c",
            "grade" : "55aae5b7848b9c8bf4ecbb4d",
            "gym" : "562e7c1ae6c3e8ce29abfe05",
            "registeredOn" : ISODate("2015-10-26T19:17:08.603Z"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("562e7c34e6c3e8ce29abfe06")
        }
    ],
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("562abaaffb5870b8fb9dca3f"),
    "grades" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("562e7bbe70ee82bb290192bd"),
            "discipline" : "55aae5b7848b9c8bf4ecbb5c",
            "grade" : "55aae5b7848b9c8bf4ecbb4c",
            "gym" : "562e7c1ae6c3e8ce29abfe07",
            "registeredOn" : ISODate("2015-10-26T19:15:10.565Z")
        },
        {
            "discipline" : "55aae5b7848b9c8bf4ecbb5c",
            "grade" : "55aae5b7848b9c8bf4ecbb4d",
            "gym" : "562e7c1ae6c3e8ce29abfe05",
            "registeredOn" : ISODate("2015-10-26T19:17:08.603Z"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("562e7c34e6c3e8ce29abfe06")
        }
    ],
}
```

I need this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("562abaaffb5870b8fb9dca3f"),
    "grades" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("562e7bbe70ee82bb290192bd"),
            "discipline" : "55aae5b7848b9c8bf4ecbb5c",
            "grade" : "55aae5b7848b9c8bf4ecbb4c",
            "gym" : "562e7c1ae6c3e8ce29abfe06",
            "registeredOn" : ISODate("2015-10-26T19:15:10.565Z")
        },
        {
            "discipline" : "55aae5b7848b9c8bf4ecbb5c",
            "grade" : "55aae5b7848b9c8bf4ecbb4d",
            "registeredOn" : ISODate("2015-10-26T19:17:08.603Z"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("562e7c34e6c3e8ce29abfe06")
        }
    ],
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("562abaaffb5870b8fb9dca3f"),
    "grades" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("562e7bbe70ee82bb290192bd"),
            "discipline" : "55aae5b7848b9c8bf4ecbb5c",
            "grade" : "55aae5b7848b9c8bf4ecbb4c",
            "gym" : "562e7c1ae6c3e8ce29abfe07",
            "registeredOn" : ISODate("2015-10-26T19:15:10.565Z")
        },
        {
            "discipline" : "55aae5b7848b9c8bf4ecbb5c",
            "grade" : "55aae5b7848b9c8bf4ecbb4d",
            "registeredOn" : ISODate("2015-10-26T19:17:08.603Z"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("562e7c34e6c3e8ce29abfe06")
        }
    ],
}
```

Nothing seems to work and closest I have to what I need is:

```
collections.users.update({
    "grades.gym": {
        $exists: true
    }
}, {
    $unset: {
        "grades.$.gym": "562e7c1ae6c3e8ce29abfe05"

    }
}, {
    multi: true
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just point to the embedded document field as your update query:

```
db.users.update(
    {
        "grades.gym": "562e7c1ae6c3e8ce29abfe05"
    }, 
    {
        "$unset": {
            "grades.$.gym": "562e7c1ae6c3e8ce29abfe05"
        }
    }, { "multi": true }
)
```